# Remove Old Branches with POWERSHELL

Tags: git, powershell

I want to remove all branches older then 3 months.

```
$branches = git branch -r
foreach($branch in $branches){

     Write-Host($branch)

     if("$(git log -- $branch --since='3 months ago')")
     {
          Write-Host("TOO OLD -> REMOVED!")
          git branch -D $branch
     }
     else
     {
          Write-Host("NOT OLD!")
     }
}
```

But it never go in this if `if("$(git log -- $branch --since='3 months ago')")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Remember to trim output from `git branch` (or use an explicit `--format` specifier)
2. Remove the `--`, otherwise `git log` will treat `$branch` as a file name

```bsh
$branches = git branch -r |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim('* ') -replace ' -> .*$'}
# or
$branches = git branch -r --format='%(refname:short)'

foreach($branch in $branches){

     Write-Host($branch)

     if("$(git log $branch --since='3 months ago')")
     {
          Write-Host("'$branch' TOO OLD -> REMOVED!")
          git branch -D $branch
     }
     else
     {
          Write-Host("'$branch' NOT OLD!")
     }
}
```

Comment: Using textual replacement on the output is quite brittle, since output formatting may be non-default. `git branch --format='%(refname:short)'` is reliable.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen How can I check if the branch ($branch) still has commits? That is, where it has been committed and has not yet been merged into the main branch.

Comment: @JamezFatout `git log $branch --not master --no-merges` might work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen He must be merged e.g. in '/origin/mainDevelopBranch' and he must not have commits that are not in this '/origin/mainDevelopBranch'

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer from Mathias, but found it to be working the other way around. For me it deleted any branches with commits within the last 3 months and kept the older ones. So I just inverted the logic and also added a grep -v to make sure that the master or main branch would never be deleted no matter what condition you search for.

```
 $branches = git branch --format='%(refname:short)' | grep -v master | grep -v main

 foreach($branch in $branches){

 Write-Host($branch)

 if("$(git log $branch --since='3 months ago')")
 {
    Write-Host("'$branch' NOT OLD!")          
 }
 else
 {
    Write-Host("'$branch' TOO OLD -> REMOVED!")
    git branch -D $branch
 }
```

}